# R - find all possible combinations of numbers WITH constraints on combination length

Tags: r, combinations

Let's say you have the following vector of numbers:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

I want to find all possible combinations of numbers with the combination length 3. The combinations must not overlap, i.e. `1, 2, 3` is the same as `1, 3, 2` and only one of those should appear in the output!

So, the answers would be:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 4
1, 2, 5
1, 3, 4
1, 3, 5
1, 4, 5
2, 3, 4
2, 3, 5
2, 4, 5
3, 4, 5
```

This is just a simple example, in reality I have a vector of length 10000 and I need to find all combinations with length 8000. What code would you use to generate those combinations in R?

Comment: `combn(1:5, 3)`

Comment: Thanks! This works. Never heard about that function until now.

Comment: Although the number of combinations of length 8,000 from a vector of 10,000 values is enormous (roughly `exp(5000)`).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately when I tried it on that vector it doesn't work anymore because the ncol value is too large

Comment: pls check out RcppAlgos

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks! That works, I managed to do it with `comboIter(1:10000, 8000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chinsoon12 suggested the package `RcppAlgos`. I investigated it and found that the following works:

```
comboIter(1:10000, 8000)
```